# Use loggable to refer to a version of Product in Order Line?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-extensions, stofdoctrineextensions

I would like to track changes of different entities and refer to a specific version from other tables. For example: in the `Orderline` table, I would like to refer to a specific version of a product.

Is the [`Loggable` extension](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle) the best way to implement this feature or should I manualy add a ProductVersion entity?

I'm using `Loggable` at this moment and I think I'm missing a feature like `$product->getCurrentVersion()` to get the current version number. Or do I misread the documentation?

Comment: do you mean by "to get the current version number" version affected to orderline ?

Comment: No, the newest version of a product. When I update a Product, it gets a new revision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this function in your Repository to get current/last version

```
public function getCurrentVersion($id)
{
    $repo = $this->_em->getRepository('Gedmo\Loggable\Entity\LogEntry');
    $log = $repo->findOneBy(array('objectId' =>$id), array('version' => 'desc'));
    return $log ? $log->getVersion() : null; // or return $log for entire object
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using **Loggable** extension this can be done with:

```
$repo = $em->getRepository('Gedmo\Loggable\Entity\LogEntry');
// your Product entity
$product = $em->find('Entity\Product', $id);
// find revisions for given product
$logs = $repo->getLogEntries($product);
if (count($logs) > 0) {
    // as it is sorted descending by version
    $currentVersion = $repo->getLogEntries($product)[0]->getVersion();
}
```

I can also recommend you **EntityAudit** extension: https://github.com/simplethings/EntityAudit

In your case that would be:

```
$auditReader = $this->container->get("simplethings_entityaudit.reader");
$revision = $auditReader->getCurrentRevision(
    'YourBundle\Entity\Product',
    $id
);
// current version number
$revision->getRev();
```

You can also:

- find entity state at a particular revision
- find changed entities at a specific revision
- find revision history of an audited entity

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest having a look at this extension for Doctrine 2 -> [EntityAudit](https://github.com/simplethings/EntityAudit#entityaudit-extension-for-doctrine2) (there's an explanation on how to install it in Symfony2).

As you can read in the documentation,

> This extension for Doctrine 2 is inspired by Hibernate Envers and
>   allows full versioning of entities and their associations.

The usage is pretty simple. You could do the following once you have it installed:

1. Specify the entities that you want to audit. Let's start by Product:

**app/config/config.yml**

```
simple_things_entity_audit:
    audited_entities:
        - MyBundle\Entity\Product
```

2. Launch an update on your DB to create the necessary tables:

`./app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

3. And then from your controller:

   ```
   class DefaultController extends Controller {
       public function indexAction() {
         ....
         $auditReader = $this->container->get("simplethings_entityaudit.reader");

         foreach( $orderLine as $product ) {// Let's assume for simplicity that this makes sense.
           $productAudit = $auditReader->find(
               'SimpleThings\EntityAudit\Tests\ProductAudit',
               $id = $product->getId(),
               $rev = 10 // Number of the revision you're interested in.
           );
           // Do whatever you please with the estate of the entity at revision 10!
         }
         ....
       }
   }
   ```

Hope it helps.

Kind regards and happy new year.